# The effect of image arithmetic on histograms

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

There are two images `f(x,y)` and `g(x,y)` and their histograms `hf` and `hg`.

If I do image arithmetic and name the result `z(x,y)` and its histogram `hz`, how can I determine `hz` as a function of `hf` and `hg`?

As far as I have found :

z(x,y)=f(x,y)+g(x,y) => hz = hf *(convolution) hg (it needs to be scaled)

How about the other arithmetic calculations?
How can I determine it on Matlab?

Comment: Each arithmetic operation has its own properties, so there is no way of getting  a generic answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is you cannot. The histogram `hz` of a combined image

```
z(x,y)=f(x,y)+g(x,y)
```

cannot be uniquely determined from the histograms `hf` and `hg` of the individual images.

Example why not:

Suppose `f` is binary and zero whereever `g` (also binary) is one. The combined histogram will most likely have a smaller variance than the single histograms. If however now the pixels in `g` are rearranged so that its histogram `hg` stays the same but correlation between `f`and `g` is maximal then the variance of the combined histogram will be larger.

The result depends on the exact images `f(x,y)` and `g(x,y)` and the histograms alone do not contain enough information.

Comment: Maybe you want some kind of approximation but then this is not specific what you really want. Also math.SE might be a better place.

Comment: it seems you're into Image Processing - could you assist us open this dedicated group: area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66531/computer-vision/72084 Just vote to questions with less than 10 up votes. Thanks.